# Getting this in ajax result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im trying to make a script that changes P lines to input fields, let user edit them and then revert back to p lines after a check in an external php document through ajax. However the problem seems to be that I cant use this within the ajax part, it breaks the code. How can I solve that? Do I need to post the HTML?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function changeshit(result, that) {
        if (result == "success") {

            $(that).closest('div').find('input').each(function () {


                var el_naam = $(that).attr("name");
                var el_id = $(that).attr("id");
                var el_content = $(that).attr("value");

                $(that).replaceWith("<p name='" + el_naam + "' id='" + el_id + "'>" + el_content + "</p>");

            });


            $(".editlink").replaceWith("<a href=\"#_\" class=\"editlink\" name=\"edit\" id=\"" + editid + "\">Bewerken</a>");
        } else {

            alert(result);
        }
    }



    $(".editinv").on('click', 'a', function () {

        var editid = $(this).attr("id");
        var edit_or_text = $(this).attr("name");

        if (edit_or_text == "edit") {


            $(this).closest('div').find('p').each(function () {

                var el_naam = $(this).attr("name");
                var el_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var el_content = $(this).text();

                $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' name='" + el_naam + "' id='" + el_id + "' value='" + el_content + "' />");

            });


            $(".editlink").replaceWith("<a href=\"#_\" class=\"editlink\" name=\"done\" id=\"" + editid + "\">Klaar</a>");

        } else if (edit_or_text == "done") {


            var poststring = "";
            $(this).closest('div').find('input').each(function () {

                var el_naam = $(this).attr("name");
                var el_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var el_content = $(this).attr("value");

                poststring = poststring + '' + el_naam + '=' + el_content + '&';

            });

            poststring = poststring + 'end=end'

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://' + document.domain + '/klanten/updateaddress.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: poststring,
                success: function (result, this) {

                    changeshit(result, this);


                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `changeshit` expects two parameters, you're only supplying one.

Comment: forgot to change that in my pasted code, it doesnt work with this in there. Entire code seems broken by adding this. Without it it only finds result correctly.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get via `this` in the AJAX response?

Comment: Since `this` is not a local variable in the function, it's not saved in the closure, so doesn't persist to the callback. That's why something  like `var that = this;` is a common idiom in Javascript.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter looks like he wants the clicked element

Comment: this has totally different context in ajax and in your function which is calling ajax. secondly jquery ajax doesn't call success function with "this" look in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the common solutions is declare a var example self = this and use that variable

```
 var self = this;
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://'+document.domain+'/klanten/updateaddress.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: poststring,
            success: function(result) {   

            changeshit(result, self);


            }
        });
    }
```

In that way, the this context is save in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Right under `$(".editinv").on('click', 'a', function () {` add

```
$(".editinv").on('click', 'a', function () {
    var element = this;
```

And then change this to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://' + document.domain + '/klanten/updateaddress.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: poststring,
    success: function (result) {
        changeshit(result, element);
    }
});
```

That is if I am understanding correctly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

If you simply add:

```
context: this
```

to the `$.ajax` options then the `success` handler will automatically be called with the correct value of `this`, so you won't need the `that` parameter.

You'll then also no longer need the extra function wrapper around the `success` callback, so you can just use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://' + document.domain + '/klanten/updateaddress.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: poststring,
    context: this,       // propagate "this"
    success: changeshit  // just pass the func ref
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can achieve this

1) If you read the docs ([jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) you'll see that you can supply a context to the ajax method

> **context**
>   *Type: PlainObject* This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that
>   represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged
>   with the settings passed to $.ajax).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://'+document.domain+'/klanten/updateaddress.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: poststring,
    context: this,
    success: function(result) {   
        // the context sent above would become the context of this function when called by jquery
        changeshit(result, this);
    }
});
```

Using it this way you could even do it like the bellow code

```
function changeshit (result) {
    var $that = $(this);
    if (result == "success") {

            $that.closest('div')... // cool ha ?
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://'+document.domain+'/klanten/updateaddress.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: poststring,
    context: this,
    success: changeshit
});
```

---

2) You can take advantage of closures ( [read more here](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) or search google ), so your code would become

```
var context = this;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://'+document.domain+'/klanten/updateaddress.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: poststring,
    success: function(result) {   
        // here you can use any variable you declared before the call
        changeshit(result, context);
    }
});
```

---

As a side note, i would recommend you use variable/object caching, so declare `var $this = $(this)` at the top of the function and use it thruought your function, instead of calling `$(this)` each time you need it.